# Sqlite3 import csv column ordering

Tags: sqlite, csv

I have a situation where I have CSV files with column names in the first row, which perfectly match the tables in my SQLite3 db, except they are in a different order. By default, with `.import table1.csv table1` SQLite3 will just treat the column names as a data row. I want it to not treat it as a data row, but use it to determine which column the data should be added to. Is this possible?

Edit: example table and CSV (however I need a solution that will work with any arbitrary table and CSV that shares the same number of columns and same names, just different ordering, like below):

```sql
CREATE TABLE crate_owners (
    crate_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    owner_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created_at TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_by INTEGER NOT NULL,
    owner_kind INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Csv:

```
crate_id,created_at,created_by,owner_id,owner_kind
208787,2020-02-14 12:34:33.454958,6128,6128,0
201200,2020-01-23 09:51:46.202886,50019,50019,0
201211,2020-01-23 10:27:14.127394,19568,19568,0
201212,2020-01-23 10:27:15.818358,19568,19568,0
...
```

Comment: A realistic sample of one of your CSV files would be helpful.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I've added a sample.

Comment: Just to be sure: no commas but those between values?  I'll be back later in the year, er, day.

Comment: yep, just the commas as shown

Answer (score 1):

create an awk script, eg. /tmp/Max888.awk, containing

```
BEGIN {
  FS=","
    C["crate_id"] = 1
    C["owner_id"] = 2
    C["created_at"] = 3
    C["created_by"] = 4
    C["owner_kind"] = 5
}
NR == 1 {
  # determine the New Order
  for (N=1;N<=NF;N++) {
    NO[N] = C[$N]
  }
  for (CO in NO) {
    NCO[CO] = NO[CO]
  }
}
NR > 1 {
  OFS=","
  # print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5
  print $NCO[NO[1]],$NCO[NO[2]],$NCO[NO[3]],$NCO[NO[4]],$NCO[NO[5]]
}
```

If your CSV data is contained in the file /tmp/test.dat, and your database in /tmp/test.sq3, you can run

```
sqlite3 -csv /tmp/test.sq3 '.import "|awk -f /tmp/Max888.awk /tmp/test.dat"  crate_owners'
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands or place them in a file and use `.read <filepathname>` command:

```
--Adjust path to location of the csv file  
.cd B:/datadir  
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS crate_owners_tmp;  
CREATE TABLE crate_owners_tmp (crate_id,created_at,created_by,owner_id,owner_kind);  
.mode csv  
.import data.csv crate_owners_tmp --skip 1  
INSERT INTO crate_owners(crate_id,created_at,created_by,owner_id,owner_kind) SELECT * FROM crate_owners_tmp;  
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS crate_owners_tmp;
```